# react native doesn't recognize project

Tags: react-native

I've made a fresh clone of a react-native project which is 100% ok and working. Installed react-native-cli, trying to run `react-native start` in the project dir, but I get `Command start unrecognized. Make sure that you have run npm install and that you are inside a react-native project.`

I tried to init a fresh project just to test, and it worked fine, I was able to run react native commands there and everything worked.

It's definitely not an issue with my project because other people work on it as well and it's 100% ok and valid. This is some issue with react native or some other lib, I suppose. What could that be?

I'm using mac os sierra and project's react native version is 0.40.0

Comment: did you run npm install?

Comment: @Nilesh yeees, I did...

Comment: @Nilesh and I'm really inside a react native project which is tested and ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've resolved this issue finally, and, to whoever it may concern: the problem wasn't with react-native. The problem was with npm. I was using yarn, and had npm 5 installed on my system. Also I had a postinstall script, which called rn-nodeify. rn-nodeify, in turn, on the final stage called npm (not yarn), and since it was npm 5 I was experiencing an npm 5 bug, which wiped out my modules. The bug is described e.g. [here](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite/issues/1101). Downgrading to npm 4 solved this issue for me.